# Validation Error messages on form load

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.6

**About the issue**

I am using Laravel 5.6.7 with vue.js. **vee-validate is being used for validation**

When the form loads, it shows validation error messages. User did not even click the submit button. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

**Code**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form role="form">                    
            <input v-validate data-vv-rules="required" type="text" 
                                                  v-model="UpdateForm.First_Name">
            <p v-if="errors.has('First Name')">{{ errors.first('First Name') }}</p>
            <button type="button">
                Update Profile
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return { 
                UpdateForm: {
                    First_Name: ''
                }
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.GetProfile();
        },
        methods: {
            GetProfile() {
                axios.post("some api url", {}).then(response => {
                    this.UpdateForm.First_Name = response.data.Data.First_Name;
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Could I get rid of validation error messages on form load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
this.editForm.First_Name = Data.User.First_Name;
```

to

```
if(Data.User.First_Name != null && Data.User.First_Name != "") {
    this.editForm.First_Name = Data.User.First_Name;
}
```

and validation is working fine now. Basically the variable is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the expected behavior. For initial validating you need to inform it with `v-validate.initial`.

Maybe you are defining this to happen when declaring v-validate or in other place.

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
new Vue({
  el: '#demo'
})
```

```css
.is-danger{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <label>This one needs touching</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" v-validate="'required'">
  <div v-show="errors.has('name')" class="is-danger">Errors: {{ errors.first('name') }}</div>
  <br/>
  <label>This one does not need touching</label>
  <input name="name2" v-validate.initial="'required'" type="text">
  <div v-show="errors.has('name2')" class="is-danger">{{ errors.first('name2') }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should i remove this one `data-vv-rules="required"` and instead put this one? `v-validate.initial="'required'" ` if so, now validation is completely not working.

Comment: when using `v-validate.initial` it will be validated before touching inputs. And what happens?

Comment: v-validate.initial or v-validate is not impacting the code.

Comment: probably because you are not adding name to the input. Try with errors.has('first_name') and add the tag name="first_name" to the input and it should work